# SIGINT in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, signals

I have the following bash script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    sleep 2
    infiniteProgramm -someParametrs
    sleep 10
    #in this line I need to stop my infiniteProgramm with bash command (SIGINT) (like Ctrl+C, but automatic)
    clear
done
```

How can I send a `SIGINT` signal to my `infiniteProgramm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: run infiniteProgram in the background:

```
infiniteProgram -someParameters &
```

Second: retrieve its PID from $!.

```
pid=$!
```

Third: kill it.

```
sleep 10
kill -2 $pid
```

2 corresponds to SIGINT, see `kill -l` for the list of all the signals.